# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un botón para poder reproducir y detener con el mismo botón la música de la pagina web que estoy haciendo?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

estoy tratando de hacer un botón que reproduzca y pause la música sin que aparezcan los controles de la música pero no lo consigo, la música se reproduce pero no se detiene, quiero que al pulsar el botón se reproduzca la música y al volver a púlsalo la detenga y al volver a pulsarlo continúe por donde iba. Esto es lo que tengo

```
    <div>
        <button onclick="playOrPause()">Music</button>
    </div>


let isPlaying = 0;
let audio;
console.log("creando audio");
audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "actualizado/Nightcore - Go Go Go.mp4"

function playOrPause() {
    if (audio.readyState < 2 ) {
        console.log("no esta listo aun");
        if (audio.error) {
            console.log("error : " + audio.error.code + "->" + audio.error.message);
        }
        return(0);
    }
    isPlaying = isPlaying + 1;
    console.log(isPlaying);
    if (isPlaying ==1) {
        audio.play();
        console.log("paused");
        isPlaying = 0;
    }
    return(isPlaying)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas una variable de control como un boolean que puedes llamar isPlaying por ejemplo (por defecto false), y al hacer click sobre el botón alternar entre ambos estados. Si haces click y el estado es false, cambias dicha variable a true e inicias/reanudas el audio, si al clickear de nuevo la variable es true cambias la variable a false y pausas la reproducción:

```
let isPlaying = false;
let audio = new Audio();
audio.src = '../Ejercicios HTML/audio/lacapital.mp3';

function playOrPause() {
  if (audio.readyState < 2) {
    console.log("El audio no está listo aún.");
    if (audio.error) console.log("Error: " + audio.error.code + "->" + audio.error.message);
  }
  if (isPlaying) {
    audio.pause();
    isPlaying = false;
    console.log("Pausado");
  } else {
    audio.play();
    isPlaying = true;
    console.log("Reproduciendo");
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has ayudado mucho